# How to specify/view C standard library man pages, and not those from another library?

Tags: cygwin, manpage

When I type

```
$ man 3 rand
```

I get a page on OpenSSL's `rand.h` file. I was expecting [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand), which is the C standard library function of the same name. I seem to certainly have the C man pages installed, as `man 3 printf` works as expected (as do other functions like `atoi`).

How can I specify the specific page I'm looking for?

I'm using Cygwin, if it matters here.

Comment: generally `man -f <term>` and then you will have a short list of choices. Each distro handles it slightly different.... frustrating...

Comment: Indeed, this is not a Bash question at all, but a Cygwin question. Retagging.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, `man -f rand` for me returns `rand: nothing appropriate`.

Comment: But `-k` works with `info`. Based on this, I was able to discover that there definitely is a `"(libc)rand" -- rand`. But I don't know how to specify that I want *that* page. I also noticed a `rand48` that I can access fine, presumably because the name is unambiguous.

Comment: That's the problems with the differences in the distributions / VM's / etc. choice of defaults for `man`. It radically effects its behavior. On Archlinux `man -f` works brilliantly (better than `man -k`), on openSuSE it is unneeded as it is part of the default. Thus my comment "frustrating..."